# Parsing JSON for use with Highcharts using jquery .parseJSON or JSON.parse: how to remove quotes from function calls for formatters?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, highcharts, formatter

So I have a JSON string that contains the following piece for formatting an axis label in highcharts:

"labels":{"formatter":" function() { return Math.abs(this.value) + \u0027%\u0027; }"

When the string is converted to a javascript object using a json parser, the object property for label.formatter is a quoted string with the function call.  Highcharts then complains because the formatter is not a function, it's a string.  Trying to figure out how to remove the quotes so that it is an actual function call, not a string.  Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

This is the entire string for reference:

```
"{"chart":{"animation":false,"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)","type":"bar"},"credits":{"enabled":false},"xAxis":{"categories":["\u0027Alta \u0027","\u0027Gratr\u0027","\u0027IDV\u0027","\u0027BSV\u0027","\u0027Adhes\u0027"]},"yAxis":{"title":{"enabled":true},"labels":{"formatter":" function() { return Math.abs(this.value) + \u0027%\u0027; }"}},"legend":{"enabled":false},"exporting":{"enabled":false},"plotOptions":{"scatter":{"marker":{"radius":6}}},"series":[{"name":"\u0027Product\u0027","data":[{"y":69,"name":"\u0027() Alta All Cap Quality Growth\u0027"},{"y":17,"name":"\u0027() Gratry International Growth\u0027"},{"y":6,"name":"\u0027(IDV) iShares International Select Div ETF\u0027"},{"y":6,"name":"\u0027(BSV) Vanguard Short-Term Bond ETF\u0027"},{"y":2,"name":"\u0027() Adhesion Cash Model\u0027"}]}],"title":{"text":"Top 20 Allocations"}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval(). Note that **this is a security hole.**

The problem is that you are passing a function via JSON. JSON does not support this.

Btw, `jquery.parseJSON()` is deprecated, use `JSON.parse()`

Here's an example:

```
data = JSON.parse(x);
data.yAxis.labels.formatter = eval(data.yAxis.labels.formatter);
```

Comment: No, eval() on the string will result in a function object that you can pass to highcharts

Comment: ok, so data.yAxis.labels.formatter = "function() { return Math.abs(this.value) + '%'; }"   Calling chart.yAxis.labels.formatter = eval(chart.yAxis.labels.formatter) I get a sytax error: Unexpected token (

Comment: Had to wrap it in Parenthesis so eval( "(" +formatter + ")" and that seems to work, thanks